Позиционирование кнопок в JavaFX (файл fxml)
Подскажите, как можно несколько кнопок разместить в разных местах в файле fxml. В моем случае, перемещение происходит всех кнопок одновременно.
Скрины прилагаются.введите сюда описание изображения.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>



<VBox spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="org.example.demo.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets  bottom="420.0" left="420.0" right="20.0" top="220.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button fx:id="button1" text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick" />

    <padding>
        <Insets  bottom="420.0" left="220.0" right="20.0" top="220.0"/>
    </padding>
    <Label fx:id="welcome" />
    <BorderPane fx:id="hi" layoutY="333" layoutX="212" />

    <Button id="er" onAction="#www" text="Добавить"/>
    <Button id="yy" onAction="#d" text="Добавить"/>


</VBox>




Код надо прилагать текстом

Как именно вы хотите перемещать? Если просто VBox целиком двигать - то можно менять паддинг слева и сверху, таким образом будет меняться расположение.

@insolor да как угодно. Но у меня ничего не получается. Чтобы я ни делал, они перемещаются все вместе.

Так не понятно что именно вам нужно.

@insolor например, расстояние между ними было больше, как по вертикале, так и по горизонтали.
